# Spy++ displaying wrong results?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have created a simple Unicode window, and I pressed a key on the keyboard to see what the value of wParam for the WM_CHAR message would be, and it gave me as expected the Unicode code point for the character, I pressed the 'S' key and my keyboard layout was set to Arabic (so the arabic character is 'س').

Now, I also captured the window messages in Spy++, but I have noticed that it gave me a wrong value for wParam, it actually gave me the value for the character code in the Windows: Arabic code page!

this is a screenshot of the results:

[image]

and this is the source code:

```
#define UNICODE

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_CHAR:
        char str[256];
        sprintf(str, "0x%.4x", wParam);
        MessageBoxA(NULL, str, "", 0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WinClass";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"WinClass", L"My Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 261, 172, 594, 384, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the following note found in the docs for `TranslateMessage` is relevant here: `"TranslateMessage produces WM_CHAR messages **only for keys that are mapped to ASCII characters by the keyboard driver** ."` (my emphasis) - on win7 with `English (Australia) - US` lang and a US keyboard layout, I get the same value displayed by both the program and spy++ (0x7A - 122)

Comment: The problem is with characters that are outside of ASCII (for example Arabic/Hebrew/Turkish/etc.), because the ASCII characters have the same values as in Unicode, so 0x7A ('z') in ASCII is the same as in Unicode (U+007A), this is why they show the same value in program and in Spy++ (but if you test an Arabic character you'll see the difference!).

Comment: The problem being asked about is why Johnny's app is receiving 0x633 but Spy++ is receiving 0xD3 instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How Spy++ works is a bit of a public secret, you can easily tell when you run `Dumpbin.exe /imports` on the .exe file.  For spyxx_amd64.exe (the 64-bit version), the most relevant entries are:

```
SPYXXHK_AMD64.DLL
   ...
                       3 SpyxxCallWndRetProc
                       2 SpyxxCallWndProc
                       4 SpyxxGetMsgProc
USER32.dll
   ...
                     320 SetWindowsHookExW
                     31F SetWindowsHookExA
```

In other words, it uses SetWindowsHookEx() to set 3 hooks, WH_CALLWNDPROC, WH_CALLWNDPROCRET and WH_GETMESSAGE.  Spyxxhk_amd64.dll is the DLL that gets injected into every process, it contains the hook callbacks.

Do note that it uses *both* the Unicode and the Ansi version of SetWindowsHookEx().  One way your result can be easily explained is when it uses the Ansi version (SetWindowsHookExA) on your Unicode window.  Such a hook can only ever observe the Ansi version of the WM_CHAR message.

Keep in mind that Spy++ has an impossible problem to solve when you run processes on your desktop that contains both Unicode and Ansi windows, which is not uncommon, it can't keep all of them happy.  The simplest assumption is that it just punts for SetWindowsHookExA as the lowest common denominator.

Actually *proving* that Spy++ gets this wrong is a lot harder to do and I putzed at it for quite a while.  Any attempt to catch Spy++ installing the hooks while using it turned out to be a bust, the hooks are installed very early at program startup.  The debugging technique I eventually discovered:

- I first located the native api entrypoint `NtUserSetWindowHookEx` by disassembling the code for SetWindowsHookExW.  On my machine (Win8.1) it is located at 0x00007FFECC3BA970.
- Started VS elevated, required to launch Spy++.
- File + Open + Project/Solution and select Spyxx_amd64.exe.
- Debug + Step Into.  This starts the program and locates the execution point at AfxWinMain (Spy++ was written with the MFC library).
- Debug + Windows + Disassembly, paste 0x00007FFECC3BA970 into the address box
- Set the breakpoint at this address.  Press F5

There are two false hits, MFC uses SetWindowsHookExW() internally.  But then it lights up, three hits that all look similar to this:

```
user32.dll!NtUserSetWindowsHookEx()     
user32.dll!_SetWindowsHookEx()  + 0x5b bytes    
user32.dll!SetWindowsHookExAW()  + 0x5b bytes   
user32.dll!SetWindowsHookExA()  + 0x11 bytes    
spyxx_amd64.exe!SetMsgHook()  + 0x6a bytes  
spyxx_amd64.exe!HookMain()  + 0x470 bytes   
msvcr120.dll!_callthreadstart()  Line 257   C
msvcr120.dll!_threadstart(void * ptd)  Line 237 + 0x5 bytes C
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0xd bytes 
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x34 bytes
```

Which is proof, you can see SetWindowsHookExA() being called.  The Ansi version, Spy++ can only ever display the Ansi version of the WM_CHAR message.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have Arabic codepage set as default in Regional Settings, and Spy++ displays the same values as you'd get in a program without Unicode support? Just a wild guess though.